# Why output is coming out to be different ? [Bitwise Manipulation]

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Complement of Base 10 Integer 

int main()
{
    int n, mask = 0, ans;
    cout << "enter a number : ";
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 0)
    {
        cout << 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while (n != 0)
        {
            mask = (mask << 1) | 1;
            n = n >> 1;
        }
        ans = (~n) & mask;
        cout << "ans = " << ans;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code of complement of integer

When I am giving an input **n = 5** output is coming out to be **ans = 7**.
It should come out to be **ans = 2**

Can anyone explain what is wrong in this ?

I am new to this platform, please don't delete my question. My earlier questions are also gets deleted due enough dislikes. I am here to learn and am still learning.

Comment: I would recommend **not** asking that your posts be moderated differently than other posts.

Comment: *"It should come out to be **ans = 2**"* -- why? That's not what your code says the answer should be, and that's what we have to go on. Walk us through the process. Start with `int n = 5` (not user input; hardcode this value), tell us the values of `n` and `mask` after each iteration of the loop, the show us the calculation of `ans`.

Comment: @JaMiT  Actually it's leetcode - 1009 question. And according to that, if user input **n = 5** then output should be **ans = 2**.
But in my case output is coming out to be **ans = 7**.

Comment: @VaibhavKumar *"Actually it's leetcode - 1009 question."* -- This tells me nothing. -- *"And according to that"* -- If you are relying on someone else to tell you what the correct output is, then you do not understand the assignment well enough to have a reasonable chance of coding it. Seek to understand why the examples have the output they do, *then* write a design, then write code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `n` is changed to `0` by the loop:

```cpp
        while (n != 0)
        {
            mask = (mask << 1) | 1;
            n = n >> 1;
        }
```

If you want to use the value of `n` later, save it elsewhere.

```cpp
        int n_original = n; // save the value of n
        while (n != 0)
        {
            mask = (mask << 1) | 1;
            n = n >> 1;
        }
        ans = (~n_original) & mask; // use saved value
```

Comment: **ans = (~n) & mask;**  But this code is outside the loop ?

Comment: @VaibhavKumar Yes, it is *after* the loop. The loop condition is `n != 0` and it has no statements that cause jump like `break`, `return`, `goto`, etc. in the loop, so program after the loop will not be executed until the condtion becomes false -- until `n` becomes `0`, in other words. Therefore, `n` must be `0` after the loop.

Comment: @VaibhavKumar I suspect that you believe the assignments in the loop only have an effect inside the loop (possibly by thinking that it's similar to the lexical scope of variables), but that's not how it works. Since `n == 0` is the only way to exit the loop, `n` is zero after the loop has exited.

Comment: @MikeCAT
what if uses **break** here  - 
   "while (n != 0)
        {
            mask = (mask << 1) | 1;
            n = n >> 1;
             **break;**
        }"

Comment: Then it is equivalent to an `if` statement: `if (n != 0) { mask = (mask << 1) | 1; n = n >> 1; }`